# How to change ListObject source from static data to a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, database, excel, vba

Right now I'm downloading data from a database using ADODB to an Excel table. However I want users to be able to refresh the table so it's updated from my database.

I've been experimenting with creating a new table from an external source and arrived to this code:

```
Public Sub CreateLiveTable(sql As String, Location As Range, TableName As String)
    With Location.Parent.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcExternal, Source:="OLEDB; " & DB_CONNECTION, Destination:=Location).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = sql
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "asdfas"
        .SourceConnectionFile = "C:\Users\lisandro.h.vaccaro\Documents\My Data Sources\172.19.179.43 Forecasting CostRates.odc"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

However I haven't been able to connect my existing table to SQL Server. I can't just delete and create it again as there are a lot of formulas and named ranges pointing to it that would be broken if I deleted it.

How can I connect my existing table to my database?

Comment: It's a great question. I remember trying to figure a way to do this in the past, but couldn't figure a way. Searching the web doesn't yield anything, so I think maybe it's not possible. Perhaps you can turn all your formulas to text by adding an apostrophe, delete the existing table, create the new one - with the same name - and then turn the formulas back on.

Comment: I thought about turning off all formulas, however this wouldn't prevent Named Ranges from breaking, and I don't see any way to turn off all of those.

Comment: You can surround the entire name definition in double-quotes. I'm not saying these are great ideas, mind you, just the best I can come up with.